# TypeError: Can't convert 'coroutine' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, asynchronous

trying to pull a JSON object from a `.json` with python 3.5.2 using async and I'm returned with this error `TypeError: Can't convert 'coroutine' object to str implicitly` and `sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Configuration.parseField' was never awaited`

**I'm using discord.py and asyncio**

What do I do?

Here is my code:

**Config**

```
class Configuration:

    # This is the hard
    FILE_PATH="config.json"

    async def parseField(fieldname):
        json = open(Configuration.FILE_PATH, 'r')
        data = json.dumps(json)
        await data[fieldname]
```

**Main**

```
bot_token = Configuration.parseField(fieldname="BOT_TOKEN")
client.run(bot_token)
```

Comment: May be OT but you are doing `json = open(Configuration.FILE_PATH, 'r')` which shadows the `json` module. That make the next line `data = json.dumps(json)` an exception waiting to happen.

Comment: What do you mean? So it's causing an exception as I'm not closing the file?

Comment: No, it's not about not closing the file. It is about using the name `json` as a variable name, when it is already used by the `json` module.

Comment: Oh okay, I've cahnged that that but I am still returned with `TypeError: Can't convert 'coroutine' object to str implicitly`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
class Configuration:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            self.data = json.load(f)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.data[name]
```

This way you can use

```
c = Configuration('config.json')
bot_token = c.token
```